# Laravel - Combine JOIN data to one result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new at Laravel and have a question about combining 2 JOIN results.

At first, I have the following tables:

videos: id, approved

videos_languages: video_id, language_id, name

Now I do the following:

```
$arr = Video::join("videos_languages","video_id","=","videos.id")->whereRaw("approved = 0")->get();
```

Then I pass the array to my view.

I get the values, but now have double results, if one video has more than 1 language. Is it possible, to combine the results of that join with Laravel into one result?

Example:

```
$arr[0]['id'] = 5;
$arr[0]['approved'] = 0;
$arr[0]['videos_langauges][0] =
{
  'name' = ...
}

$arr[0]['videos_langauges][1] =
{
  'name' = ...
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You can group by id, then of course languages can be omitted if a video has more than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = Video::distinct()->join("videos_languages","video_id","=","videos.id")->where("approved", 0)->get();
```

That should clean up duplicates from your results. Also note `where()` instead of `whereRaw()`.